# Is it Ok to make the exports object a function in CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

In the case the a CommonJS module only need to return one function, is it good practice to assign it directly to the exports object? (as opposed to assigning it as the only attribute of the exports object)

For example (imaginary `log.js` module):

```
module.exports = function(text){console.log(text);}
```

usage:

```
var log = require('./log');
log('something');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I often use this practice myself. It's also a good fit with the revealing module pattern, e.g.:

```
module.exports = function(db) {
    return {
        get: function(id, callback) {
            // db.get(...)
        },
        save: function(obj, callback) {
            // db.save(...)
        }
    }
};
```

It's also widely used in connect (e.g. [csrf module](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html)) and express (e.g. [route](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L10)).